# How to make a variable accessible across all pages in HTML / Template (Django)..?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I am using Django-Python for my project..I have created a "Master HTML page" and all other pages extends this master page..

There is a Drop down (Select Menu) in Master page..and i want to access the value of selected option across all Django Function and views..

How can i achieve that..??

Comment: Did you find either answer on this question useful? If so, upvote them, and if you think any solves your problem, you should accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution would be to assign the value of the select menu's selected value to a session variable via post (a jQuery ajax post may be less obtrusive).

Somewhere in your view:

```
if request.POST:
    request.SESSION['select_menu_value'] = request.POST.get('select_menu_value')
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, presumably you are dealing with form posts whenever you want to access the option you refer to.

You could either have your whole page be contained by a form, or use javascript to set a hidden field within your main form which is submitted.

You can then access it as a raw property of the POST object, or bind a Form object to handle it.

Comment: But the fact is the drop down is not in any form...It is just on the Site Base (Master page) which is extended by every other page..!!